# Reporting progress using a Follower

Tags: rust

My goal is to implement a function that accepts a `Follower` object that will be used to report progress through a complex function (a depth-first traversal of a graph). Here's my attempt:

```rust
pub trait Follower<'a, N> {
    fn root(&mut self, node: &'a N);
}

pub fn depth_first<'a, N>(
    node: &'a N, follower: &mut dyn Follower<'a, N>
) {
    follower.root(node);

    // TODO
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::fmt::Display;

    struct DebugFollower<'a, N> {
        nodes: Vec<&'a N>
    }

    impl<'a, N: Display> DebugFollower<'a, N> {
        fn new () -> Self {
            DebugFollower { nodes: vec![ ] }
        }

        fn to_string(&self) -> String {
            self.nodes.iter().map(ToString::to_string).collect()
        }
    }

    impl<'a, N> Follower<'a, N> for DebugFollower<'a, N> {
        fn root(&mut self, item: &'a N) {
            self.nodes.push(item);
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn walks_p1() {
        let mut follower = DebugFollower::new();

        depth_first(&0, &mut follower);

        assert_eq!(follower.to_string(), "0");
    }
}
```

The code compiles and performs as expected. However, I suspect that, in trying to silence the many compile errors I encountered, I may have added unnecessary lifetime parameters. Previous experience has shown me that it's very easy to get into a situation wherein so many useless parameters have been added that removing them one at a time isn't possible. Still, I have tried to do that and can't find any lifetime parameters that can be removed.

In particular, I'm suspicious of the lifetime parameter on `Follower`, which appears to leak implementation details from `DebugFollower`. For example, removing the `nodes` property from `DebugFollower`, and updating the rest of the code, `Follower` no longer needs a lifetime parameter.

Does this example follow idiomatic Rust use of lifetime parameters? If not, how can I improve the use of lifetime parameters here?

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the lifetimes completely, just replace every instance of:

```
&'a N
```

with just:

```
N
```

[See Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48c01c536c25205dfeaef4c63a68fea6)

But why? Well, in your current code N is inferred to be i32. However, with my suggested changes N will be inferred to be &'a i32. If you allow Rust to infer the reference it will also infer the correct lifetime for you.

But does this, as you ask, leak implementation details of `DebugFollower`? Not from a Rust perspective. In Rust, ownership details are very much part of the interface and not just an implementation detail. The key issue is that the `Follower` trait has to specify how long the references will be valid so that `DebugFollower` knows how long it is allowed to store those references.